# How do i find low security systems from map?

Tags: elite-dangerous

So I have a massive bounty that needs paying off, and to do that I need to find one of those low security systems to talk to one of those dudes that can pay it off (not specific I know, but that's not important). but no matter how long I look I can't find one. I know there used to be a way that you could see low security systems (or any security system) in the galaxy map, but I can't find it. Did they remove it or am I just not finding it? I's appreciate your feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's still there.

- Go to Galaxy map
- Then the fourth tab in the left sidebar (the one with five stars)
- Pick map
- And then pick "Security" in the first "Map view configuration" dropdown. You'll have to scroll down in the dropdown, it's easy to miss you can do that. :)

Don't forget you can check which services a station provides in the system map, so you don't have to visit every station checking if the dudes are there.

Comment: Note that there is actually a filter for "Interstellar Factors" now, but I think it only shows up after you go to that system.